# What does a Scandinavian Flick/Pendulum Turn physically achieve?

Tags: technique, auto-racing

From what I gathered a Pendulum Turn in the context of rallying helps with inducing oversteer, primarily on low-grip surfaces. Many resources explain the technique, but less so what actually makes it efficient. I figure that some advantages are:

1. The initial sideways drift gives more traction than braking in a straight line.
2. Weight is distributed towards the tires on the side of the corner.

But I do not think that this it the primary effect of the technique. So, is the idea of the pendulum, especially in a FWD, that the rear of the car holds the front of the car back (just as the anchor point of a pendulum), thus introducing a moment of inertia towards the corner into the car when the brakes are being released? Also, this would not work in an RWD at all (only if the rear wheels grip faster than the front wheels when releasing the brake)?

Is this what makes it work? Are there any factors missing? A qualitative physical explanation would be great.